# How to get result set by checking a specific element in an aggregated array using JOOQ?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I want to filter results by a specific value in the aggregated array in the query.

Here is a little description of the problem.
Section belongs to the garden. Garden belongs to District and District belongs to the province.
Users have multiple sections. Those sections belong to their gardens and they are to their Districts and them to Province.

I want to get user ids that have value 2 in district array.
I tried to use any operator but it doesn't work properly. (syntax error)
Any help would be appreciated.

ps: This is possible writing using plain SQL

```
rs = dslContext.select(
                        field("user_id"),
                        field("gardens_array"),
                        field("province_array"),
                        field("district_array"))
                .from(table(select(
                        arrayAggDistinct(field("garden")).as("gardens_array"),
                        arrayAggDistinct(field("province")).as("province_array"),
                        arrayAggDistinct(field("distict")).as("district_array"))
                                .from(table("lst.user"))
                                .leftJoin(table(select(
                                        field("section.user_id").as("user_id"),
                                        field("garden.garden").as("garden"),
                                        field("garden.province").as("province"),
                                        field("garden.distict").as("distict"))
                                        .from(table("lst.section"))
                                        .leftJoin("lst.garden")
                                        .on(field("section.garden").eq(field("garden.garden")))
                                        .leftJoin("lst.district")
                                        .on(field("district.district").eq(field("garden.district")))).as("lo"))
                                .on(field("user.user_id").eq(field("lo.user_id")))
                                .groupBy(field("user.user_id"))).as("joined_table"))
                .where(val(2).equal(DSL.any("district_array"))
                .fetch()
                .intoResultSet();
```

Comment: There's no reason for this question to have received 3 downvotes. It's perfectly legitimate as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is calling [`DSL.any(T...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any(T...)), which corresponds to the expression `any(?)` in PostgreSQL, where the bind value is a `String[]` in your case. But you don't want `"district_array"` to be a bind value, you want it to be a column reference. So, either, you assign your `arrayAggDistinct()` expression to a local variable and reuse that, or you re-use your `field("district_array")` expression or replicate it:

```java
val(2).equal(DSL.any(field("district_array", Integer[].class)))
```

Notice that it's usually a good idea to be explicit about data types (e.g. `Integer[].class`) when working with the [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) API, or even better, use the code generator.

Comment: Cannot resolve method **'equal(org.jooq.QuantifiedSelect<org.jooq.Record1<T>>)**
This is the exact error I'm getting.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: can you please check the syntax?

Comment: @AshanTharindu, I made a mistake, it should be `Integer[]` because you're using `arrayAgg()`, but as far as compilation errors are concerned, it shouldn't matter